# get "error :lvalue required as left operand of assignment " when set value for register

Tags: c

I can't not solve this problem. I don't understand why. Here is my simple code

mjpeg.h:

```
    #define START_REG                 (*(volatile unsigned int*) BASE+0x000)  
    #define MJPEG_PIC_START_RD                                  (0x00000001)
```

mjpeg.c:

```
    void encStreamInit(void){
    START_REG |= MJPEG_PIC_START_RD;
    }
```

test.c:

```
    int main(void){
     encStreamInit();
     return 0;
    }
```

It get "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment" when compiling.
Please help me. Thank for your help.

Comment: From your spacing, I wonder if you meant `( *((volatile unsigned int*)BASE+0x000) )` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not make any sense. Prefix `*` has higher operator precedence than binary `+`. Thus `(*(volatile unsigned int*) BASE+0x000)`  will get interpreted as this:

- I assume BASE is an `int` or `unsigned int`.
- Cast BASE to the type `(volatile unsigned int*)`.
- Take the contents of that pointer. The result is an `unsigned int`.
- Add the value `0x0000` to that result. The result is of type `unsigned int`.
- Since this result is not a lvalue, you cannot use |= on it.

The fix is simple:

`(*(volatile unsigned int*) (BASE+0x000))`

Answer (score 2):

`START_REG` gets expanded to `(*(volatile unsigned int*) BASE+0x000)` so you can not call  `|=` on it. What you do is the same as `(a+1) |= 2` - `a + 1` is temporary, you can not use it for `|=`.

EDIT: maybe the problem you have is that you meant to `|=` the value pointed by the adress. To achieve this, move the asterisk out of the brackets in the `START_REG` macro:

```
#define START_REG                 *((volatile unsigned int*) BASE+0x000)
```

Comment: A dereferenced pointer is a valid lvalue, though. `*(p + 1) |= 2` is still perfectly legal.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev but here the asterisk is within the brackets due to operator precedence

Comment: The OP's problem is that the expression is malformed and the intention was probably different.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev I am not sure what was the OP's intention. Still nothing in my answer is wrong. The macro gets expanded as I say and then the problem is what I describe. If that is not what the author meant to write still my answer should be helpful. I will add a note to fix the answer as you propose.

Comment: It wasn't wrong before the edit, but it was certainly misleading.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

mjpeg.h:

```
    volatile unsigned int * START_REG = BASE+0x000; /* BASE needs to be #define here- */
    #define MJPEG_PIC_START_RD                                  (0x00000001)
```

mjpeg.c:

```
    void encStreamInit(void){
    (*START_REG) |= MJPEG_PIC_START_RD;
    }
```

Comment: The dereferencing can still be in the macro itself, it's just the order of the operations that matters, as Charles Bailey pointed out.

Answer (score -1):

When you use `define`, it will just make a substitution of text. What it will not do, is defining a variable. In your case, you want to use those constants as variables and use operator between them.

```
a |= b
```

is equivalent to

```
a = a | b
```

So this means you use OR operator for your constants and try to assign the result to START_REG constant, which is not applicable.